# Rewrite URL to Wordpress which included CodeIgniter

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, routes

I have a CI site which has Wordpress installed on the sub-directory.
Specification:
-IIS 7.5
-PHP 5.3

The original CI site:

website.com

Everytime I access  **website.com**  , it would add 2 variables. Internationalization and the controller.
It would redirect the site to **website.com/id/user**.

```
id=> Indonesian
user=>Controller
```

Because of this , on accessing Wordpress ( **website.com/blog/**), it add those two variables too.
It would redirect the site to **website.com/blog/id/user**
On Wordpress, I have included the CI index.php so I can call the CI view in Wordpress.

route.php

```
 $route['default_controller'] = "user";
 //$route['blog/id/user'] =  $route['default_controller'];
 $route['404_override'] = '';    
 $route['^(id|en)(.+)$'] = "$2";
 // '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
 $route['^(id|en)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

How can I change the URI not to add the two variables; `language` and `controller_name`?
I have tried modifying the routes.php but it did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use .htaccess for this like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.site.com/id/user/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Im using IIS for server So I can only use web.config . Do you have solution for web.config?